# Direct admin subdomain not on public name server

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain

I have a problem with subdomain not being on public name server.

I created sub-domain in direct admin (omfrontend.dutchbridge.nl, it adds records for ftp.omfrontend.dutchbridge.nl and mail.omfrontend.dutchbridge.nl) and waited more than one day after creating.

But when I do

```
host ftp.omfrontend.dutchbridge.nl 8.8.8.8
```

it returns

```
Using domain server:
Name: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
Aliases: 

Host ftp.omfrontend.dutchbridge.nl not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

At the same time checking it on a private name server:

```
host ftp.omfrontend.dutchbridge.nl ns5.dutchbridge.nl
```

returns

```
host ftp.omfrontend.dutchbridge.nl ns5.dutchbridge.nl
Using domain server:
Name: ns5.dutchbridge.nl
Address: 176.31.95.96#53
Aliases: 

ftp.omfrontend.dutchbridge.nl has address 176.31.95.96
```

Also just omfrontend.dutchbridge.nl without 'ftp.' works.

Here are my dns records:

```
ftp                        A   176.31.95.96
mail                       A   176.31.95.96
omfrontend.dutchbridge.nl. A   176.31.95.96
omfrontend.dutchbridge.nl. NS  ns5.omfrontend.dutchbridge.nl.
omfrontend.dutchbridge.nl. NS  ns6.omfrontend.dutchbridge.nl.
omfrontend.dutchbridge.nl. MX  10 mail  
_domainkey                 TXT "o=~"    
omfrontend.dutchbridge.nl. TXT "v=spf1 a mx ip4:176.31.95.96 ~all"  
x._domainkey               TXT "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA1m3JFmhUuxxlxGMBtR9PPgQSQSp1WAmFV2MHD9vjK2gsD2U/Do1Ht/uLqvvRKynfGU41axwht98tiiRCCp6bjCP
0FobLNvl7/doJk/avbJdb/v8AyJVR2mpnFAsuYUCo/umSHTViyM5UokkKwzxmN5MPPmLjIi/TGDbWIf6lZu/jBO+vqjE6yA0/xwAN5lThzc94Y59nYWTSiSUtoSwEVMlFTdE1h5vSz9hTL4nttjznG
Hs/OdJjn+9JoCMYuoQu7W83Iizo7jjq0X3f2U2JHFYiFoPDsw8/uPLgRhxGLgk7D6yCDrfY4bUAUNnbdyy8z2XTlIX/OrXtGM1p6QPRbQIDAQAB"    
localhost                  AAAA ::1
```

Comment: Where is this configuration and what is the `$ORIGIN` for records without FQDN?

Comment: sorry, don't quite understand what you meant in your sentence

Comment: Your domain's authoritative name servers are `ns109.ovh.net` and `dns109.ovh.net`. Does this admin panel modify the settings on these nameservers? And second, `$ORIGIN` is the part that will go after the lines without FQDN, e.g. `ftp A   176.31.95.96` -> `ftp.$ORIGIN A   176.31.95.96`. So here, you don't have `ftp.omfrontend.dutchbridge.nl` if the origin is not `omfrontend.dutchbridge.nl.` but `dutchbridge.nl.`.

Comment: One day ago I have added `ftp.omfrontend.dutchbridge.nl A 176.31.95.96` but it didn't, so I have added now `ftp.omfrontend.dutchbridge.nl. A 176.31.95.96` (the difference is in dot after FQDN). But still it doesn't seem to be the problem to me, otherwise `host ftp.omfrontend.dutchbridge.nl ns5.dutchbridge.nl` wouldn't work, correct? Also I checked that `host omfrontend.dutchbridge.nl dns109.ovh.net` works. Unfortunately can't check how the connection works between ns5 and dns109. So currently have no thoughts about it. Anyway post you answer I will check it as 'best answer'. Thanks.

Comment: That wasn't an answer but for gaining more information. My answer is below and should help you understand the situation, if I got it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your OVH hosted domain `dutchbridge.nl` has two [authoritative DNS servers](http://www.noip.com/blog/2013/11/22/authoritative-dns-vs-recursive-dns-work/),

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
dutchbridge.nl.         7200    IN      NS      ns109.ovh.net.
dutchbridge.nl.         7200    IN      NS      dns109.ovh.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns109.ovh.net.          3600    IN      A       213.251.128.153
dns109.ovh.net.         3600    IN      A       213.251.188.153
```

According to OVH, they are [these servers](http://help.ovh.com/NewDNSServer) and managed through this [Control panel](https://www.ovh.com/manager/web/login/) that should have section **Domain & DNS**.

I assume that you have [DirectAdmin](http://www.directadmin.com/) Web Control Panel installed on your hosted server `omfrontend.dutchbridge.nl`. It can be used to manage your server, which also happens to have DNS server installed, as the `ns5.dutchbridge.nl` mentioned has the very same IP `176.31.95.96`. However, that DNS server is **not the authoritative server of your domain**.

It seems that you could use OVH's DNS servers [also for secondary DNS](http://help.ovh.com/InstallSecondaryDNS) if you wish to have your own server as the primary server. It can be configured through the [Control panel](https://www.ovh.com/manager/web/login/) too. Since OVH's DNS has TTL of 24 to 36 hours using it as secondary may give you more flexibility.

Comment: wow, you've spent so much time on answer, that is really awesome. I haven't yet investigated all the links you've sent but I will. Thanks. Btw, I do a little frontend and backend development mainly on php, so if you ever have a question that you might think will be too silly to ask on stackoverflow, please contact me.